# How to display the value of an attribute of a setting (incOptions or updateOptions) in sbt shell?

Tags: sbt

It's sbt 0.13.6.

Given `updateOptions` and `incOptions`, how can I display the value of their attributes in sbt shell?

I can `show` their stringified representation, but I'd like to know what's the current values of `latestSnapshots` for `updateOptions` and `nameHashing` for `incOptions` are.

```
> show incOptions
[info] IncOptions(3,0.5,false,false,5,None,<function0>,true,true,false)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Sep 14, 2014 1:12:49 AM
> show updateOptions
[info] sbt.UpdateOptions@701f8b18
```

I can do it quite easily in `consoleProject` with:

```
scala> incOptions.eval.nameHashing
res0: Boolean = true

scala> updateOptions.eval.latestSnapshots
res1: Boolean = false
```

and am looking for similar one-liners at sbt shell with `eval`. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one way to show this attributes in sbt shell. My idea is to assign such attribute to existing boolean option and then show this option.

I created option 'zzz' in build.sbt file:

```
val zzz = settingKey[Boolean]("")
```

Then in sbt shell I write:

```
set zzz := updateOptions.value.latestSnapshots
```

and then:

```
show zzz
```

Here is my shell log:

```
> set zzz := updateOptions.value.latestSnapshots
[info] Defining *:zzz
[info] The new value will be used by no settings or tasks.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to hello (in build file:/D:/sbt/hello/)
> show zzz
[info] false
> set zzz := updateOptions.value.consolidatedResolution
[info] Defining *:zzz
[info] The new value will be used by no settings or tasks.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to hello (in build file:/D:/sbt/hello/)
> show zzz
[info] true
```

Comment: I don't like to have the fake setting just to be able to evaluate another using `.value` macro. The issue is that I would need to create as many settings as all the types I would like to evaluate settings to. Since it's the only answer at the moment after quite a long time, I'm to accept it only.